# jquery does not load after page redirect 

Tags: asp.net

i have 2 pages default.aspx & show.aspx , when i run only show.aspx by setting it as start page , jquery loads & everything goes fine .

but when i redirect from default.aspx to show.aspx , jquery does not load in show.aspx

default.aspx & show.aspx have diff master pages , i am loading jquery as below :

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="contentPanel1" runat="server">

    <script type ="text/javascript" src ="JScripts/jquery-1.2.6.js">
    </script>
```

i have tried by putting in master page of show.aspx but it does not work?

the problem occurs only when i am redirecting from default.aspx to show.aspx

Thanks,

Comment: What isn't executing? That is, how do you know that jquery isn't loading?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that show.aspx is in a different folder and the js file path is not being resolved.

You may be having the Default.aspx and it's master file  in the same location, but Show.aspx and it's master file in different locations.

To test this point it to google's cdn instead.
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js